# onClick is not called in my viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a viewpager with several fragments in the viewpager.I need to handle click event.I have already implement the onTouch event,but its not trigger for click event.When i swiping onTouch is triggering.I don't know why it's not trigger for click event.

This is my viewpager class

```
    package com.android.ho;

import com.sph.custom.ViewPagerWithTapGestreDetection;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class PDFActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ImageOnTapCallback,OnPageChangeListener{
    static final int ITEMS = 20;
    MyAdapter mAdapter;
    //ViewPager mPager;
    ViewPagerWithTapGestreDetection mPager;
    //ViewPager mPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_pager);
        try {
            mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            mPager = (ViewPagerWithTapGestreDetection) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            mPager.setId(5000);
            mPager.setImageOnTapCallback(this); 
            mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            //mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);      
            mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);

            /*
            Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.first);
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                }
            });
            button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.last);
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mPager.setCurrentItem(ITEMS - 1);
                }
            });
            */

            mPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                    view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    Log.e("Inside onTouch onTouch onTouch onTouch onTouch onTouch ", "onTouch");

                    return false;
                }
            });


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

        public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
            super(fragmentManager);
        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return ITEMS;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {


            switch (position) {
            case 0: // Fragment # 0 - This will show image
                return MyFragment.newInstance("1.pdf");
            case 1: // Fragment # 1 - This will show image
                return MyFragment.newInstance("2.pdf");
            case 2: // Fragment # 1 - This will show image
                return MyFragment.newInstance("3.pdf");
            case 3: // Fragment # 1 - This will show image
                return MyFragment.newInstance("4.pdf");
            case 4: // Fragment # 1 - This will show image
                return MyFragment.newInstance("5.pdf");
            default:// Fragment # 2-9 - Will show list
                return MyFragment.newInstance("1.pdf");
            }


        }
    }



    @Override
    public void tapDetected() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("tapDetected", "tapDetected");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("onPageScrollStateChanged", "onPageScrollStateChanged");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("onPageScrolled", "onPageScrolled");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("onPageSelected", "onPageSelected");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.e("onDestroy", "onDestroy onDestroy onDestroy");
    }




}
```

This is my fragment class

```
package com.android.ho;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;

import com.epapyrus.plugpdf.core.viewer.ReaderView;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyFragment extends Fragment{
    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "EXTRA_MESSAGE";
    public static int count = 1;

    static String file;
    TextView txt;
    ReaderView readerView;

    public static final MyFragment newInstance(String message) {
        MyFragment f = new MyFragment();
        Bundle bdl = new Bundle(1);
        bdl.putString(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        f.setArguments(bdl);
        file = message;
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myfragment_layout, container, false);
        try {

            File fl = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/pdf/2.pdf");
            readerView = (ReaderView) v.findViewById(R.id.pdfviews);
            //readerView.setOnClickListener(this);
            Log.e("readerView", fl.toString());

            v.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                    view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    Log.e("Inside onTouch onTouch onTouch onTouch onTouch onTouch ", "onTouch");

                    return true;
                }
            });


            // readerView.openFile("/mnt/sdcard/pdf/1.pdf","");
            if (count > 5)
                count = 1;
            readerView.openFile("/mnt/sdcard/pdf/" + count + ".pdf", "");
            Log.e("Inside onCreateView count is ", "" + count);
            count++;

            v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Cilcked..",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });

            /*v.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                    view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    Log.e("Inside onTouch onTouch onTouch onTouch onTouch onTouch ", "onTouch");

                    return false;
                }
            });*/

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return v;
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {

        super.onDestroyView();
        // Log.d("PDFVIEW", "onDestroyView");

        try {
            if (readerView != null) {
                readerView.clear();
                // readerView.clearAllField(5);
                // readerView.destroyDrawingCache();
                // readerView.
                // readerView=null;
                // mPDFView.purgeMemory();
                // mPDFView.destroy();//added to force release memory
                // mPDFView = null;
            }
            Log.e("Fragment onDestroyView ", " onDestroyView readerView is "+readerView);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }



}
```

This is my custom viewpager class

```
package com.android.ho

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Currency;
import java.util.Date;

import com.sph.bh.ImageOnTapCallback;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ViewPagerWithTapGestreDetection extends ViewPager {

    private ImageOnTapCallback imageOnTapCallback;
    private GestureDetector tapGestureDetector;
    private OnGestureListener mGestureListener;

    public ViewPagerWithTapGestreDetection(Context context) {

        super(context);
        try {
            imageOnTapCallback = null;// set if needed
            mGestureListener = new GestureListener();
            tapGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getContext(), mGestureListener, null, true);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    public ViewPagerWithTapGestreDetection(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        try {
            imageOnTapCallback = null;// set if needed
            mGestureListener = new GestureListener();
            tapGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getContext(), mGestureListener, null, true);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }



     @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
                //Don't let any touches be passed down to the children automatically
         Log.d("onInterceptTouchEvent ", "onInterceptTouchEvent");
                return true;
         }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d("onTouchEvent", "onTouchEvent");
        if (imageOnTapCallback != null) {
            tapGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    public ImageOnTapCallback getImageOnTapCallback() {
        return imageOnTapCallback;
    }

    public void setImageOnTapCallback(ImageOnTapCallback imageOnTapCallback) {
        this.imageOnTapCallback = imageOnTapCallback;
    }

    public class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {





        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {

            Log.d("onSingleTapConfirmed", "onSingleTapConfirmed");

            if (null != imageOnTapCallback) {
                imageOnTapCallback.tapDetected();
            }

            return super.onSingleTapConfirmed(e);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
            Log.d("onDoubleTap", "onDoubleTap");
            return super.onDoubleTap(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            Log.d("onLongPress", "onLongPress");
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
            Log.d("onScroll", "onScroll");
            return super.onScroll(e1, e2, distanceX, distanceY);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            Log.e("onFling ", "onFling");
            return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
        }
    }
}
```

Now when i click it identified by the onInterceptTouchEvent in the ViewPagerWithTapGestreDetection class.So i need to view a Horizontal scrollbar when i click.Is it the correct way to call it inside onInterceptTouchEvent ?

Comment: could you add some code?

Comment: Maybe you return true when your onTouch with down action is triggered.Then onclick will not be triggered.

Comment: Try to implement click listener to Fragment parent layout.

Comment: I change the code as above.Now it always return true from onInterceptTouchEvent mthod.Now after onInterceptTouchEvent mthod it runs onTouchEvent in main class as well as fragment.Also it runs onSingleTapConfirmed and tapDetected methods.Why it runs all of these methods ?